# How to form a given list of elements in python to create another set of lists from it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, wxpython, ipython

```
List1 =['000095', '000094', '000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000095']
```

def makecycle(list, startElement):

A loop which forms the bottom list which is made from the upper one's elements!

if i pass that function the start element and the list it shoul print like this:

```
makecycle(list1, 000094) it should print:
['000094', '000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000095', '000094']
and if pass 
makecycle(list1, 000101) it should print:
['000101', '000099', '000096', '000095', '000094', '000092', '000101']

and if pass 
makecycle(list1, 000092) it should print:
['000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000095', '000094', '000092']
```

i know its kinda not clear enough but thats all i can point!

Comment: Whats with all these python tags?  It can't be all of them

Comment: Start by trying to write some code.  Post the code you have here and tell us exactly what part you're having trouble with.

Comment: Why do you want the first and last items to be the same? That makes this simple task a little harder than it ought to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def makecycle(list1,startElement):
   ind = list1.index(startElement)
   l = len(list1)
   i = ind
   list2 = []
   while ind < (l-1):
      list2.append(list1[ind])
      ind = ind + 1

   for x in range(i):
       if list1[x] not in list2:
          list2.append(list1[x])

   print(list2)
```

Comment: Its very very close when i called the funtion with these valusers makecycle(list1, 000094) it prints:
['000094', '000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000094']
but there is one element missing it should print:
['000094', '000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000095', '000094'] Thanks man

Comment: and when i passed 000096 it returns:  ['000096', '000096']

Comment: What actually should be the general output ? Please specify .

Comment: the output depends on the passed list and the starting element both if i pass 000096 its the second last element of the given list, so the newly formed list would start from that and the next element whats in the right(000095) and then whats in the left excluding  the duplicate of (000095) which is '000095', '000094', '000092', '000101', '000099' and then finnishing with the starting 000096  and then  the output is gonna be:
['000096',000095', '000094', '000092', '000101', '000099', '000096', '000095']

Comment: check it now, is it ok?

Comment: 'type' object is not subscriptable at line if list[i] not in list2:    i'm having that problem

Comment: Thanks it works fine now!

Comment: @ Luv33preet, if i get/retreive the list from text-field or db there is strange thing going on that i do not understand 
if i pass makecycle(List1, startElement) where list1 is from db or field
List1 = order_cycle 
print(order_cycle) = ['000089', '000093', '000090', '000089']
print(startElement) = "000093"
the output is: ['0', '0', '0', '0', '9', '3', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '0', '0', '0', '0', '9', '0', "'", ',', ' ', "'", '0', '0', '0', '0', '8', '9', "'", '[', '000093']
instead of : ['000093', '000090', '000089', '000093']
is there anything you could do? i was trying to solve it 24hrs